# Suggestion to merge cranks and crankset

Tags: discussion, tagging

[crankset](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crankset) and [cranks](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cranks) have similar number of questions, one does not have a wiki.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've suggested that they be merged. Basically, anyone who has at least +5 in answers with cranks or crankset should be able to upvote (or downvote) the synonym.

I like crankset as the master for cranks, so I did it that way.

You can vote here:
https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested&tab=newest

Answer (score 3):

The way it currently stands, the cranks tag seems to specifically describe the crank *arms*. I would suggest that we create a description for crankset that is inclusive of all the pieces of the crankset and then set cranks as a synonym.

I have no opinion on whether or not we would then want to create a new crank-arm tag. I guess I'm leaning toward not doing so and just having those questions included in the crankset tag, but I don't have a strong opinion about it.

Comment: Actually what you are describing is what I think should be done. However, I do not have the reputation to edit tags.

Comment: I too would like to see these two tags merged. How can we draw the attention of someone with enough reputation to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I too would like to see these two tags merged. How can we draw the attention of someone with enough reputation to do this ?